# Transfer items from one location to another

Tags: excel, vba, inventory-management

I want to transfer equipment from one location to another and create a change log. I have the change log portion figured out.

I am struggling to subtract specific equipment from one plant and add to another plant. The reason this is difficult is because the plant receiving the equipment may not have a line created for them in the master database. Basically the section at "ndstep".

I have 3 sheets. First sheet is equipment transfer form (see image 1) which uses a specific item number, the plant transferring from and transferring to along with the quantity. Column I is used to lookup the plant and item number in column A on the Master Database sheet. The data on the right after column "I" identify the plants with the same equipment.

The database (Image 2) has the plant, equipment number "Item number" and the Qty on hand.

```vb
Sub TestMod_Transfer()

Dim FindREQUIP As Range
Tequip = Sheet1.Range("I3") 'Transfering Plant&Equipment type
Requip = Sheet1.Range("I4") 'Recieving Plant&Equipment type
TQTY = Sheet1.Range("F3") 'QTY transfered
'loop for Midwest sheet
LastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
NRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) = Tequip Then
        'subtract from the tranfering plant
        Sheet2.Cells(i, 6) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 6) - TQTY
        Sheet2.Cells(i, 8) = Now
        GoTo ndStep
        ''''''''''''figure out how to exit if statement once found....
    End If
Next i
ndStep:
Set FindREQUIP = Sheet2.Range("A:A").Find(what:=Sheet1.Range("I4").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not FindREQUIP Is Nothing Then
    If Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) = Requip Then
        Sheet2.Cells(i, 6) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 6) + TQTY
        Sheet2.Cells(i, 8) = Now
        'MsgBox "Existing Line Has Been Modified For Transfered Equipment"
        'Exit Sub 
    End If
Else
    'NEED TO CREATE NEW LINE WITH DATA
    Sheet2.Range("D" & NRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("C3").Value
    Sheet2.Range("B" & NRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("G3").Value
    Sheet2.Range("F" & NRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("F3").Value
    MsgBox "New Line Created For Transfered Equipment"
End If
    
End Sub
```

Image 1: Equipment Transfer Form
[image]

Image 2: Master Database
[image]